# Um duvida em relação ao toggle button

Tags: html, jquery, css

eu fiz um toggle button utilizando esse codigo:

```js
// Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.clickme {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
<div class="box">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
<div class="box">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Mas estou com um problema bem chato em relação a quando se clica em mais de um toggle button eles acabam acumulando e fica bem feio
img normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
img com os toggle buttons em show.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom eu queria q só tivesse como abrir um por vez ou quando um abrir o outro fechar é possível fazer isso? Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voce pode utlizar o collapse bootstrap, e um script para altenar o fechamento das divs como por exemplo

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var active = true;
    $(document).on("click", ".accordion ","show.bs.collapse", function () {
        if (active)
            $(".accordion .in").collapse("hide");
    });
```

Comment: Mano eu não achei nenhum plugin pra baixar vc sabe dizer oq eu chamo na script p funcionar? Ou usa apenas esse codigo q vc mandou?

Comment: Você tem que acrescentar o Jquery

Comment: https://jquery.com

Comment: Adicionar o bootstrap , baixe e acrescente no projeto  junto com jquery

Comment: eu consigo acrescentar ele no meu codigo já feito?

Comment: O q eu estou foi feito pelo j query só estou com esse probleminha chato ;x

Comment: Sim baixe o jquery coloque em uma pasta e usando a tag <script src=“js/jquery.js”></script> - exemplo - acrescente tanto o jquery quanto o bootstrap, vale a pena também você estudar a ambos principalmente os componentes do bootstrap e o jquery, pois ambos são largamente utilizados

Comment: Eu já tenho os 2 baixados pow e eu criei o toggle pelo jquery só não sei como vou adicionar ao meu codigo jquery esse plugin do bootstrap ..

Comment: tou meio perdido kk

Comment: Eu usei o codigo q o francisco comentou, mas o toggle abre e fecha bem rapido eu queria q ele abrisse e ficasse só fechasse qnd abrisse outro .

Comment: Entendi, na verdade você deve acrescentar a estrutura html com o bootstrap pra ter o collapse, e acrescentar o jquery que passei, o código html que coloquei contém o bootstrap, você pode usá-lo como referência para codificar seu html

Answer (score 1):

Para fechar todos os que já estão abertos, só iterar neles e dar outro toggle:

```
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.each($('.box[style*="display: block"]'), function(i, v){
             $(v).slideToggle('fast');
        });

        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n3mfva6/1/).

Comment: obrigado mano!!

Comment: Francisco eu estou com um problema eu adicionei, mas qnd clica para abrir o toggle ele fecha sozinho e não quando abre outro toggle pode ajudar pff?

Comment: @Felipe Toggle ou collapse?